# Mobile-friendly web design: How to programmatically zoom out after text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, viewport

I've got a webpage that looks and functions okay in both desktop and mobile browsers IMO, but I've been unable to solve a particular UX functionality.

When a user clicks/taps on a text field for searching, the mobile browsers zoom to the text box for data entry.. *This is good and I want to keep it!* ..but how do I reset the page scale/zoom/transform afterward?

**I want to zoom out programmatically after the user stops typing..** But nothing I've Googled and/or tried has worked.

**Of note: If you double-tap most-any element, the browser will reset the scale/zoom, but I'm clearly using the wrong keywords or asking the wrong questions to identify this behavior..**

All I seem to find are solutions for disabling user-scaling via the viewport meta tag, which is not what I want, or questions similar to this one that remain unanswered.

---

Here's some stuff I've tried:

1) Simulating a double-tap via the YUI, I had high-hopes for this..

```
<!-- required in the head node -->
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.13.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

// Then elsewhere in script, simulate a double-tap on the DIV containing the input.
YUI().use('node-event-simulate', function(Y)
{
    var node = Y.one("#left");
    node.simulateGesture("doubletap", {point: [4, 4]});
});
```

2) This didn't work..

```
window.parent.document.body.style.zoom = 1.0;
```

3) Using JQuery to zoom to "window" or "body" at a scale of 1 also failed..

```
$("window").animate({ 'zoom': 1}, 400);
```

4) Then I got excited when I considered using CSS to do a [transform2d](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) on my outer-most DIV, but to my chagrin, it didn't work..

```
$('#outer-div').css("transform", "scale(1,1)");
$('#outer-div').css("-ms-transform", "scale(1,1)");
$('#outer-div').css("-webkit-transform", "scale(1,1)");
```

5) Finally, I've tried declaring a viewport meta tag and manipulating it in the runtime, but this isn't working on several levels; either I get no apparent change in state, or if I do get a change, the scaling is "just wrong" in several respects (some text will be missing, divs are sized wrong, the Google Map canvas gets wicked-jacked).

```
// Replace..reset the viewport metatag via JQuery..
//
var theWidth = $(window).width();
$('#vp').remove();
$('head').append('<meta id="vp" name="viewport" content="width='+ theWidth.toString() + '/>');

// Or this pure javascript approach..
//
var vp = document.getElementById('vp');
vp.setAttribute('content','width='+theWidth.toString());
```

Anyway, I hope what I'm asking is somewhat clear. Basically, how can I programmatically recreate the zooming out that occurs when I double-tap most any element on the page?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That is handled at the WebView layer, unclear that your js even knows it's zoomed in-on.

Comment: @pfrank, the fact that I can double-tap to trigger page rescaling leads me to believe there _must surely be_ some kind of call or event I can fire in the code that sets the rescaling into motion. Is this incorrect, are you saying this level of control is exclusive to native apps?

Comment: The double-tap is forwarded to the html from the webview (the webview gets the first shot at it).  So totally possible that the webview makes this decision abstracted away from the actual html

Answer (score 2):

I think the js meta viewport one is the most promising: You could set the viewport meta tag after loosing focus on the input, just like you did in one exapmle - together with a window.resize() call is js, which is missing in the example - this should trigger a zoom out. I cant try it right now myself, so no guaranty that there will be no messups like you discribed, but maybe worth a try ;)

```
$('input[type="textarea"]').on('focusout', function(event) {

    $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'height=device-width,width=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0');
    $(window).resize();

});
```